# Mobile Push notification shows sent but user is not receiving it, either in iOS or android platform

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, mobilepush, push-notification, status

In SF marketing cloud we are using journey builder to send a push notification, the status says sent successfully and says "delivered"  but message is not received by bothe the iOS and an andriod user, can anyone suggest a solution ?

Comment: A lot of things can be wrong. I suggest you run the MobilePush Detail Extract Report https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_mp_run_the_mobilepush_detail_extract_report.htm&type=5 and check the status of the messages you are sending, you’ll possibly get more detailed error messages.

Comment: @RachidMamai - The MobilePush Detail Extract Report shows the the status as successfully and shows delivered - NO ERROR message is there  ** but still the message is not received by both the iOS and Android.

Answer (score 0):

If the push notification shows as sent is not received on the device, you'll want to refer to the SDK troubleshooting documentation.

https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/trouble-shooting/trouble-shooting-push-setup.html

https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/trouble/ios-debugging.html